# bulk inserts with SQLite and CoreData

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, insert, bulk

I have  a CoreData model that uses SQLite  as persistence store. I need to insert large numbers of rows after doing some processing to each record. Is there any way to send those commands to SQLite

```
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF
PRAGMA count_changes=OFF
PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY
PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY
```

I need to speed up the processing time, as it takes couple of hours to complete.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can specify the pragmas when adding your store to the store coordinator:

```
NSMutableDictionary *pragmaOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"synchronous"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"count_changes"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"MEMORY" forKey:@"journal_mode"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"MEMORY" forKey:@"temp_store"];
NSDictionary *storeOptions =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:pragmaOptions forKey:NSSQLitePragmasOption];
NSPersistentStore *store;
NSError *error = nil;
store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
            configuration: nil
            URL:url
            options:storeOptions
            error:&error];
```

(Adapted from [Persistent Store Features](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html))

I strongly suggest to also read "Efficiently Importing Data".

Related documentation:
[NSSQLitePragmasOption](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSSQLitePragmasOption)
[Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1)

Comment: You should be aware of the consequences the memory mode has: If something bad happens (crash, exception, force quit, ...) you will lose the data which is in the in memory journal. If this is what you want: Go for it.

Comment: is there a journal_mode = OFF mode?

Comment: Yes. journal_mode = OFF. But if I were you I would not use this option either. There are a lot of other things you can do to improve performance when importing data. Playing around with the pragmas is only a last resort. Read the documentation I linked.