# How much time it takes to insert bulk mount of data into CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

In my application i am downloading thousands of records, and i have to inert them in to CoreData.

I have to estimate the time to download and process the data.
Downloading time depends on the user's interned speed.

Can you please tell me how much time it takes to insert 10000 records in CoreData?

Thanks,
Jack.

Comment: It depends on the data, the number of relations, etc. etc. But most likely downloading it is going to be slower than storing it.

Comment: less than 1 seconds it takes to insert 5,000 records in CoreData. I also depends upon data

Comment: depends on the data of course so it doesn't make any sense to throw a number at you :)

Comment: 3 hours more or less (possibly 3 hours less)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking several questions in one and they have been answered already. Let me wrap it all up and give you further information regarding your question.

- Time of bulk inserts: Depends on the kind of data and on the computation power / hard disk of your device. It also depends on how you actually perform the bulk insert.
- Improve Performance if needed: There are many things you can do to increase the performance. If you encounter performance problems when inserting objects in bulk please have a look at the following post on Stackoverflow: [Improving Performance of Bulk Inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911388/bulk-inserts-with-sqlite-and-coredata/9001738#9001738). There is also a chapter in the Core Data Programming guide which is called Efficiently Importing Data which you should read. [Core Data Programming Guide: Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1)
- Estimating remaining time of the download: A naive calculation of the time remaining would only take the current speed and the number of remaining bytes to download in consideration. This is usually a very bad estimation which jumps around a lot. In order to smooth the estimation you should use a [Moving Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). A moving average takes previous values in consideration. An [algorithm which makes use of a moving average to estimate the remaining time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779600/how-to-estimate-download-time-remaining-accurately) can be found on Stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check yourself by inserting NSLog-commands after the download is finished and another one after the CoreData operation is finished?

The consol will give you exact timestamps of the start/end of the operations.

Like David Rönnqvist said before: In most cases downloading takes way longer than inserting items into the database.